# How to determine if api service is blocking requests from VPS

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, digital-ocean

This works from my development machine (MacOS):

```
import requests
r=requests.get('http://api.usno.navy.mil/rstt/oneday?date=today&loc=Sacramento,CA')
```

But not from my VPS (Ubuntu LTS). From the VPS I get:

*requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='api.usno.navy.mil', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /rstt/oneday?date=today&loc=Sacramento,CA (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out',))*

Same version of Python (3.6) and requests (2.20.1) on both systems.

"*Max retries exceeded with url:*" is clearly not the problem, since I can access it from the MacOS machine.

How can I get requests to provide more information, such as determine if the IP of my VPS is being blocked from the API provider?

I am able to access http://www.airnowapi.org and https://api.weather.gov from both systems and receive a 200 status.

Comment: `Max retries exceeded with url: ...` is the libraries way of saying "I've tried to create a connection to the server a couple of times, but never succeeded". So you can't say it's "clearly not the problem". Could be a lot of reasons, maybe a firewall interfering with outgoing connections, network problem, ...

Comment: Under the hood `requests` tries multiple times. That's why you are getting the wording `Max retries exceeded with url`. Try to use `requests` to access other URLs from other services. If you are getting the same error, then it might be a firewall issue or similar. If not then the timeout error is your client telling you that you are blocked. To go around this you need something like a proxy service, or get a new IP, or the like.

Comment: Added: "I am able to access http://www.airnowapi.org and https://api.weather.gov from both systems and receive a 200 status"

Comment: Perfect. Then you're good to go. When you get `requests.exceptions.ConnectionError` you are blocked by `navy.mil` or your ISP for that particular service. Use a proxy service. I recommend [crawlera](https://scrapinghub.com/crawlera). No affiliation, just like them. One IP and it rotates proxies for you.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that on November 20, 2018 they have updated their api to version 2.2 which now uses HTTPS. Might want to update your URL to reflect that change.
`r=requests.get('https://api.usno.navy.mil/rstt/oneday?date=today&loc=Sacramento,CA')`